# sbt compile play framework application error

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

With my current scala play application, I have tried to install Java and set their paths into environment variables.

To run application, I am using sbt. While hitting **sbt compile** command with command prompt, I am getting following error message on command prompt.

```
C:\user\project\tcreadapi-cmtcsqlapi>sbt compile
[info] Loading settings for project tcreadapi-cmtcsqlapi-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\user\project\tcreadapi-cmtcsqlapi\project
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:176)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.JrtClassPath.asURLs(DirectoryClassPath.scala:204)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$asURLs$1(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.asURLs(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.findMacroClassLoader(Macros.scala:66)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.findMacroClassLoader$(Macros.scala:65)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.findMacroClassLoader(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.$anonfun$defaultMacroClassloaderCache$2(MacroRuntimes.scala:56)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable$perRunCaches$$anon$1.apply(SymbolTable.scala:457)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.defaultMacroClassloader(MacroRuntimes.scala:58)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.defaultMacroClassloader$(MacroRuntimes.scala:58)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.defaultMacroClassloader(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes$MacroRuntimeResolver.resolveRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:76)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.$anonfun$standardMacroRuntime$3(MacroRuntimes.scala:38)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:206)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike.getOrElseUpdate$(MapLike.scala:203)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.standardMacroRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:38)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.standardMacroRuntime$(MacroRuntimes.scala:31)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.standardMacroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$14.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:448)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$14.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:401)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroRuntime(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroRuntime$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.pluginsMacroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.macroRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.macroRuntime$(MacroRuntimes.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.macroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.$anonfun$expand$1(Macros.scala:619)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global.withInfoLevel(Global.scala:219)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.expand(Macros.scala:613)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.apply(Macros.scala:600)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand(Macros.scala:764)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand$(Macros.scala:762)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.standardMacroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$12.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:432)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$12.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:401)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.pluginsMacroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand(Macros.scala:757)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand$(Macros.scala:757)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.macroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.vanillaAdapt$1(Typers.scala:1163)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1223)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1196)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5631)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:5701)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5572)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4746)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:693)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4748)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4776)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5571)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:5701)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5572)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4746)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:693)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4748)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4776)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5571)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.computeType(Typers.scala:5692)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.assignTypeToTree(Namers.scala:1079)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.valDefSig(Namers.scala:1629)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.memberSig(Namers.scala:1798)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.typeSig(Namers.scala:1763)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$ValTypeCompleter.completeImpl(Namers.scala:910)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$LockingTypeCompleter.complete(Namers.scala:1960)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$LockingTypeCompleter.complete$(Namers.scala:1958)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$TypeCompleterBase.complete(Namers.scala:1953)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1530)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.initialize(Symbols.scala:1678)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5240)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5681)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1999)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedModuleDef(Typers.scala:1868)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5538)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5681)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5247)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5540)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:441)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.run(Analyzer.scala:96)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.$anonfun$compileAndLoad$1(Eval.scala:248)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.compile$1(Eval.scala:248)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:253)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:218)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalDefinitions(Eval.scala:161)
[error]         at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDefinitions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:326)
[error]         at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:151)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:1136)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$discoverProjects$2(Load.scala:1144)
[error]         at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:127)
[error]         at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse$(MapLike.scala:125)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:1143)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$discoverProjects$4(Load.scala:1151)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:58)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:51)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:1151)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:1165)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:862)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:937)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:726)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$11(Load.scala:729)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:729)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:688)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:484)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:176)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:241)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:546)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:562)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:492)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:471)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:251)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:251)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:829)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:829)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:800)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
[error]         at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]         at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]         at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
[error]         at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:130)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:111)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:37)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:119)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:20)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:176)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.JrtClassPath.asURLs(DirectoryClassPath.scala:204)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$asURLs$1(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.asURLs(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.findMacroClassLoader(Macros.scala:66)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.findMacroClassLoader$(Macros.scala:65)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.findMacroClassLoader(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.$anonfun$defaultMacroClassloaderCache$2(MacroRuntimes.scala:56)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable$perRunCaches$$anon$1.apply(SymbolTable.scala:457)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.defaultMacroClassloader(MacroRuntimes.scala:58)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.defaultMacroClassloader$(MacroRuntimes.scala:58)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.defaultMacroClassloader(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes$MacroRuntimeResolver.resolveRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:76)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.$anonfun$standardMacroRuntime$3(MacroRuntimes.scala:38)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:206)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike.getOrElseUpdate$(MapLike.scala:203)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.standardMacroRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:38)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.standardMacroRuntime$(MacroRuntimes.scala:31)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.standardMacroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$14.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:448)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$14.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:401)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroRuntime(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroRuntime$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.pluginsMacroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.macroRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.macroRuntime$(MacroRuntimes.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.macroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.$anonfun$expand$1(Macros.scala:619)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global.withInfoLevel(Global.scala:219)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.expand(Macros.scala:613)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.apply(Macros.scala:600)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand(Macros.scala:764)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand$(Macros.scala:762)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.standardMacroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$12.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:432)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$12.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:401)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.pluginsMacroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand(Macros.scala:757)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand$(Macros.scala:757)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.macroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.vanillaAdapt$1(Typers.scala:1163)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1223)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1196)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5631)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:5701)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5572)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4746)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:693)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4748)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4776)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5571)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:5701)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5572)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$38(Typers.scala:4746)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:693)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4748)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4776)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5571)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.computeType(Typers.scala:5692)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.assignTypeToTree(Namers.scala:1079)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.valDefSig(Namers.scala:1629)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.memberSig(Namers.scala:1798)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.typeSig(Namers.scala:1763)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$ValTypeCompleter.completeImpl(Namers.scala:910)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$LockingTypeCompleter.complete(Namers.scala:1960)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$LockingTypeCompleter.complete$(Namers.scala:1958)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$TypeCompleterBase.complete(Namers.scala:1953)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1530)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.initialize(Symbols.scala:1678)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5240)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5681)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1999)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedModuleDef(Typers.scala:1868)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5538)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5681)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5247)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5540)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:441)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.run(Analyzer.scala:96)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.$anonfun$compileAndLoad$1(Eval.scala:248)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.compile$1(Eval.scala:248)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:253)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:218)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalDefinitions(Eval.scala:161)
[error]         at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDefinitions(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:326)
[error]         at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:151)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:1136)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$discoverProjects$2(Load.scala:1144)
[error]         at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:127)
```

build.sbt file of project contains following dependency :

```
 scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  ehcache,
  javaWs,
  javaJdbc,
  openId,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.6.3",
  "org.webjars" % "swagger-ui" % "3.17.1",
  "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.0.0.jre8",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.6.1",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.197" % Test,
  "com.auth0" % "java-jwt" % "3.8.1",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.7.19" % Test,
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.9",
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-core" % "1.7.0" % Test,
  "de.bechte.junit" % "junit-hierarchicalcontextrunner" % "4.12.2" % Test
)
```

plugin.sbt file have dependencies like :

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.15")
addSbtPlugin("com.sensatus" % "sbt-build-info-conf" % "1.2.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-jacoco" % "3.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.1.3")
```

Version of jdk installed is:

```
C:\Users\LBHX04>java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Can you bump scala version to the latest (2.12.10) and see if it solves the issue?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, but still am getting same response.

Comment: Could you print the result of `sbt -v` and the sbt version in build.properties?

Comment: result of sbt -v is : "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe"
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss4M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-cp
"C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\\bin\sbt-launch.jar"
xsbt.boot.Boot

## Also build.properties contains : sbt.version=1.2.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems SBT has somehow picked up a JDK 13, which is not really supported by the Scala ecosystem, until now.

Ensure to run SBT with JDK 8 or 10 or 11.

---

BTW, you can run SBT with `sbt -J-showversion` to see which Java Runtime you use.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a different version on build.properties file, setting this to the same version as the version installed/version used to load sbt fixed the problem.
sbt.version = 1.3.8

Answer (score 0):

1. Scala can be used from maven as a dependency or can be locally installed in the system. make sure to use the right one.

Checking the version compatibility document available here can help resolve the errors :
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html